# Primefaces - menubar - submenu background in collapsed state

Tags: css, primefaces, submenu, menubar

I've got question about how to edit style (specifically background color) for submenu label which is in collapsed state. There's no need to post code. Links to images below.

1. In this case submenu label is hovered. (Using .ui-menuitem-link:hover).

[Case one](http://iis.pwsz.elblag.pl/~13883/1.png)

2 In this case menuitem is hovered, submenu is collapsed and it's background color turns to gray. So I'm interested how to access those state of submenu to change it's background to another color.

[Case two](http://iis.pwsz.elblag.pl/~13883/2.png)

Couldn't display images due to low reputation. Thanks.

Comment: expalin your requirements clearly, you are confusing

Comment: Code is always a great idea as it provides us a starting point to simulate your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amarnath said, your questions i a bit confusing. If I understood correctly you want to specify different styles for activated menu and submenu.

Lets say you want the first level of the menu to have a red backgroud and the the second level to have a green background. You could do that using plain css as follows:

```
ul li.ui-menuitem-active>a{
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color:red !important;    
}

li ul li.ui-menuitem-active>a{
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color:green !important;    
}
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't notice that ul and li elements are responsible for menubar too. Thanks and sorry for being a bit confusing.